# Eigen::Map<Sparse> for COO-SpMV

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, eigen3

Here is my question in short:
What is the correct code for generating a map for an (unsorted) coo-matrix in Tux Eigen (C++)?

The following code succeeds at generating a map A_map for a compressed row storage (crs/csr) format sparse matrix, that is stored in a crs_structure A1. (I use metis notation. m=rows, n=cols, nnz=#nonzeros.)

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::SparseMatrix< double,Eigen::RowMajor,myInt>> A_map(A1.m,A1.n,A1.nnz,A1.adj,A1.adjncy,A1.values,NULL );
```

I use the following code in attempting to generate a map A_map for a coordinate storage (coo) format sparse matrix, that is stored in a coo_structure A2. ptrI,ptrJ,ptrV are int64*,int64*,double*, giving row-,col-coordinates of values in ptrV.

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::SparseMatrix< double,Eigen::RowMajor,myInt>> A_map(A2.m,A2.n,A2.nnz,A2.ptrI,A2.ptrJ,A2.ptrV,innerNonZerosPtr);
```

I need the map because I want to benchmark Eigen's sparse matrix vector product (matvec) against mine.

In general, none of the indices of A are sorted.
Otherwise, the csr format could be created from the coo format in $\cO(nnz)$, circumventing the issue.

That is not an option here because sorting the indices consumes far more time then computing the matvec.

Side note:
I hove not understood what the "innerNonZerosPtr" means; I failed at finding its actual explanation in the Eigen documentation.
Possibly, understanding its intention and purposeful use in my scenario could solve my problem.

Cheers, and many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example here [sparseTutorial](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html)

For row-major case, innerNnz vector stores the number of non-zero elements of each rows.
If matrix is in compressed form, innerNnz is non required.